# Where to get php_perl.dll while pecl4win is down?

Tags: php, perl

I need to call a Perl script from a PHP file, and I've gotten as far as know that I need the Perl class, and that it's in the php_perl.dll extension.  I've also downloaded the php_perl package from PECL, but as you know, it's just the source and needs to be compiled.  I don't work in C, so compiling it's not really an option -- I tried downloading Visual Studio Express but I still can't seem to make it happen.

So I really need php_perl.dll, but http://pecl4win.php.net/ext.php/php_perl.dll just tells me that "The pecl4win build box is temporarily out of service. We're preparing a new build system."  Surely there must be SOMEWHERE else I can get the DLL, but I can't seem to find it.  Every link I find seems to either be someone else looking for it, or a warez-looking site that wants you to give them your credit card info.

Thanks...

----  Nick

Comment: pecl4win.php.net is gone forever and won't be coming back.  Your next-best source is probably http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ , but there's no php_perl.dll there.

Comment: thanks for letting me know not to wait. :(  I guess I'm just going to have to figure out how to compile it myself.  Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Internet Archive Wayback Machine results](http://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://pecl4win.php.net/ext.php/php_perl.dll) look promising, perhaps one of the links will lead you to the file (although they often take such binary files out of the archive).

EDIT: I was able to get the DLL for the older branch `php-5.0.5 (5_0)` that way and <strike>uploaded it [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/EIj9MyDj/php_perl.html)</strike> (removed). Or try the [direct link](http://web.archive.org/web/20080615132923/http://pecl4win.php.net/download.php/ext/5_0/5.0.5/php_perl.dll).

Looking for the newer branch `php-5.1.6 (5_1)` however gave no results so far, I checked the 4 most recent dates.

EDIT2: Found another [working link](http://web.archive.org/web/20061209152122/http://pecl4win.php.net/download.php/ext/5_1/5.1.2/php_perl.dll) for branch `php-5.1.2`.

Comment: Thanks for the upload, that was great of you.  Unfortunately the old DLL doesn't work with the current version of PHP. :(  ('The procedure entry point _zval_copy_ctor could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll.')

Comment: OK, I'll remove the uploaded file and let you know if I should find a way to get the newer version.

Comment: Looks like that should work if you've got perl58.dll.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [sidebar](http://windows.php.net/)
says to use the following repository until the new buildsystem is online:

http://downloads.php.net/pierre/